# Rails best practices for writing .js.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry if this question has been asked before

I've started using a lot of **js.erb** files in my rails apps and I can't really find any information on the best practices for this sort of thing. Right now I'm cobbling bits an pieces of [other](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) [people's](http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) code

I know [when and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127697/js-erb-vs-js) to use js.erb, but I'm looking for a total d*psh*t's quide on **how** to write **js.erb** - syntax rules, do's and don't's etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I started I found I often used js.erb to transfer data from the server to the client, i.e:

```
var username = <%= user.name %>;
```

Using one interpreted language to dynamically write code in another interpreted language felt very wrong, so now I rarely use js.erb.  Instead I set the server actions to output data in JSON format, and then use Javascript on the client to download the JSON and parse it into Javascript objects, so code and data stay separate.

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't use .js.erb because it will meet serious problem when user.name is changed. if you want to pass variable to js you can try gem [client variable](https://github.com/coffa/client_variable).