# Rails 3, remote form redirecting, want to stay on page, missing template error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, submit

I think I must be doing something stupid. Unfortunately, due to the nature of stupidity, I can't tell what I'm being stupid about. So, as you can guess, I feel pretty stupid.

Please help me surmount this brick wall of stupidity.

I want to be able to click on a submit button and not leave the page, moreover, for that page to not even attempt to reload! This is accomplished by ajax and I've read several guides on it, I have even had it working on another project before. In this instance I'm hiding the div with scriptaculous. In the previous version of ajax form submission I used a (pseudo code)

```
   render update do |page| 
       page replace html with this div 
   end
```

But this time I'm not actually going to replace the div or anything, I'm just hiding it with scriptaculous with an onclick event....

Alls I want is for the form to actually submit and for it to disappear.

So I'm working on a form, here's the form tag:

```
        <%=form_for :call_back_request, :remote => true, :url => {:action => "call_back_request_cbrsent"} do |c| %>
```

As you can see it is *:remote => true*

I have various form entry fields, which I think are more or less irrelevant, here's the relevant parts:

This is a field that is part of the submit button, so I've included it here:

```
    <%= hidden_field_tag :instructor_id, "empty", :id=>"instructor_hidden_field" %>
```

this is the submit button, as you can see I'm using scriptaculous to hide a div, that's the div the the submit button is in.

It could be affecting this so rather than delete that from this stackoverflow question I've included it.

```
    <%=c.submit 
    :value=>"SEND", 
    :style=>"width:90px; height:33px; padding-bottom:0; font-size:1em;", 
    :class=>"lpl-go-button lpl-go-button-submit", 
    :onclick=>"Effect.BlindUp('cbr_row_#{rp[:name]}');  document.getElementById('instructor_id').value = '#{rp[:instructor_id]}';return false;", :remote=>true %>
```

(line breaks added by me here to prevent you guys having to scroll right so much)

From the controller :

```
      def call_back_request_cbrsent
        @call_back_request = CallBackRequest.new(params[:call_back_request])
        @instructor = Instructor.find_by_id(params[:instructor_id])
        @call_back_request.instructor_id = params[:instructor_id]
        @call_back_request.save
        email = UserMailer.create_send_call_back_request(@call_back_request, @instructor)
        email.set_content_type("text/html")
        UserMailer.deliver(email)
      end
```

Now, the thing is, as far as my tired mind can see the return false; & the remote => true (in the submit tag specifically) do nothing much. My brain's cache is totally chock a block, I am having trouble thinking. Feel like I need to take a step back and stuff cause I'm not seeing the problems here.

Thanks to anyone who takes the effort to get through my ramblings here to give me an answer, I appreciate that I've got a lot of waffle up there. Really sorry. Dead tired. Think Dr. Jonestone said "sorry I didn't have time to write a short one" - bit of that going on here.

*Just to clarify, currently I'm getting missing template error on a remote form...* I tried adding this

```
    render :nothing => true
```

But, it iss not working.

It does a good job at rendering a blank page, I don't know what the point in this would be so I am assuming that either it is not working properly for me or it's not appropriate in this context for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (in your controller)

```
render :nothing => true
```

Edit:

Ah, if you had a template error you should've said so.

I just noticed that you want to remove the div also.

So what you want to do, it in your controller:

```
def call_back_request_cbrsent
....
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
end
```

And then make a `call_back_request_cbrsent.js.erb` file in your views. This will contain the javascript to remove that form. It obviously contain something like the following:

```
$("#form").remove()
```

...That's in jQuery, but just use whatever javascript you've been using to remove the form.

Comment: Thanks for this, but that just renders a blank page, it literally renders nothing. That's to say with it in the controller I get a blank (white/empty) page. Without it I get template missing.

Comment: Righty oh! I'll try giving this a shot. Thanks for coming back to me with another answer, really appreciate that. Essentially what this will be doing is giving a somewhat redundant function back through to that page (to remove the div which I've already hidden)? Redundant in the sense that it's hidden already .. but not redundant in the sense it gives my rails something to do and makes it feel happy and useful? ho ho ho

Comment: Also, sorry for not mentioning the template error. Think I have a spot of spongy bovine on the go here.

Comment: Just gotta ask, is this really what RoR expects people to do when they just want to do a remote form? Could it be that I have mislead you somehow in my question or written something so wrong in my code that the solution is this? Simply put, this feels to me like a monkey hack on a pretty conventional thing to do - remote form submission with no page changes.

Comment: @LpLrich Yep, this is what everyone does for this. It's not really that hacky if you think about it. You're just telling the controller to respond to a javascript request with a bit of javascript, and an html request with an html page. Given, I'm not sure why render :nothing isn't working (probably b/c of form submission), but if you want to remove the form and everything this is the best way.

Comment: Maybe because the form is not for the page I'm on, as such. If the form for was the same action as what rendered the page then maybe? But that would be a bit annoying too for various other reasons. Thanks for getting back to me again by the way. While I've got you, you don't happen to know the prototype for the jquery you wrote off the top of your head? Also, when you say "make a javascript file in your views" and actually call it js.erb, this is the first time I'll have done that - you do actually mean .js.erb and in views as apposed to a regular js file in with my other ones? Thanks for this

Comment: Ah wait, I don't want to remove the form. I only have one form. I have multiple submit buttons. The form will stay but the div will go. I'm guessing that's pretty much the same difference as what you were saying above, but just clarifying here.

Comment: If anyone finds this page by Google and like me starts wondering about the difference between .js and js.erb then check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127697/js-erb-vs-js

Comment: @LpLrich If this solved your problem, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: I made a js.erb file and I continue to get a template missing error. You know the type: Template is missing 

Missing template main/call_back_request_cbrsent with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html] ....... (bla bla bla bla bla)

I put bogus js inside the js.erb, I figured 'heck, I don't care if it removes the div or not, I just want my blooming form to work'. 

Brain is absolutely stack overlowing now and I require a break so I'll have to leave this til tomorrow. I still think there must be a 'simpler' (so to speak) solution out there and I just can't see the wood for the trees right now.

Comment: I'm going to give you the plus one as I can see that this is (a/the) correct answer. I don't particularly like it though. Not that it's your fault, this is a Rails issue I'm not happy with. I've not implemented this as I have not quite figured it out yet, so if anyone wants to add any answers I'd be delighted.

Comment: This evening I realised that I'm hitting brick walls because I need to get used to using ujs not rjs, essentially. It is also looking more and more like I should get on the jquery band wagon at some point.  Anyone reading this who also needs to get up to speed with this sort of thing start here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript 
Thanks for the help!