# pass javascript date variable to rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fullcalendar

I have an application where jquery fullcalendar is implemented. On day click I need to pass the selected date as params to rails controller. When I alert the date inside dayclick function, I am getting the date in the format of  "Tue Oct 30 2012 12:40:20 GMT+0530 (IST)".. But when I pass as params in jquery ajax to rails controller, it is passing blank. How do I get it in rails controller successfully. Please find my code for dayclick below.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  var date = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
  alert(date);
  $.get("<%=update_projects_admins_users_path%>",
    {
      id:'<%=params[:user]%>',
      date_selected: date
    },
    function(data) {
      $('.active_projects').html(data);
      //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
  );
  if (allDay) {
    alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code in controller? also are you getting any error in firebug console?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the $.get call using a manually constructed url string:

```
 $.getScript("/controller/action/params")
```

So an example of this would be something like:

```
  $.getScript("/posts/increment_view_count.js?id="+id)
```

This would route the request to the "posts" controller and to the "increment_view_count" action.

You need to remember a few things when implementing this:

1. You need to make sure you have a route in routes.rb file with matching http verbage(get, post, etc) to allow javascript to access the controller action.
2. You must make sure that the controller action will respond to javascript requests.  By default, controllers will not do this so you can either make all actions in the controller accessible to javascript requests by putting:

   ```
   respond_to :html, :js
   ```

at the top of your controller.  Or create a respond_to block inside the method like so:

```
def index
 @people = Person.find(:all)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
 end
end
```

I am also using "$.getScript" instead of "$.get" which might be something else you want to look at.

Comment: Also, js.erb files are only accesible from the server and not from the client so embedding Ruby in your client-side js files will not work.  See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127864/853006