# Rails 3: Instance variable inaccessible in .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a really simple page, where I need to generate some dynamic JavaScript for a photo gallery. Something intuitively simple, but which I'm struggling with greatly. In my controller I am building a list of `Photo` as `@photos`, then need to iterate out some JavaScript for each photo in my `photo.js.erb` file.

However, whenever I reach my .js.erb file, the `@photos` variable becomes nil... what am I missing?

**controllers/photos_controller.rb** file:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  layout "application_photos"
  def category
    @photos = ...(generates collection of Photos)...
  end
end
```

**views/photos/category.html.haml** file:

```
= content_for :head do
  // @photos is still initialized at this point
  = javascript_include_tag "photos"

// This partial only loads some more markup, it's inconsequential.
= render :partial => 'default_slideshow'
```

**javascripts/photos.js.erb** file:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // Throws NilClass error
    <% puts 'Photos: ' + @photos %>
});
```

I know this question has been asked a dozen times, but none of the previously accepted answers actually worked for me. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: remember this: asset files don't have access to instance variables declared in a controller.

Comment: Ok, good to know. How would I work around this?

Comment: Can't you just build your `category.html.haml` view and then jQueryize what's on the page? do you really need to access `@photos` from the JS? If you really need to, then you'll probably have to render the `.js.erb` as a view from the controller.

Comment: Mike is right.  what are you planning to do with @photos?

Comment: Two more details: 1. I'm leveraging a jQuery plugin where I need to generate some JS inside that jQuery function to initialize it, 2. I wanted to put the JS in its own file for 'neatntess' and because HAML sucks to print content into directly, especially nested JS. (however, if that isn't an option, I'll bend.)

Comment: not sure exactly, did you try to use respond_to or respond_with to use js instance var. on rails ?

Comment: I have not utilized `respond_to` or `respond_with` at all.

Comment: then try to write a block straight after @photos on controller: respond_to do |f|
f.js
end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send js request to the server in order to have access to the instance variable. Something like this

```
$(function($){
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "..."
    })  

});
```

In views/photos/category.js.erb file:

```
alert("<%= j @photos %>")
```

Or you can do the same using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem.

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<head>
 <title>some title</title>
 <%= include_gon %>
 <!-- include your action js code -->
 ...
```

You put something like this in the action of your controller:

```
@your_int = 123
@your_array = [1,2]
@your_hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
gon.your_int = @your_int
gon.your_other_int = 345 + gon.your_int
gon.your_array = @your_array
gon.your_array << gon.your_int
gon.your_hash = @your_hash

gon.all_variables # > {:your_int => 123, :your_other_int => 468, :your_array => [1, 2, 123], :your_hash => {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}}
gon.your_array # > [1, 2, 123]

gon.clear # gon.all_variables now is {}
```

Access the varaibles from your JavaScript file:

```
alert(gon.your_int)
alert(gon.your_other_int)
alert(gon.your_array)
alert(gon.your_hash)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I like the strategy, but the implementation still isn't working quite yet. I'm hung up on the controller which isn't rendering the `category.js.erb` file for the corresponding `category` view, despite having a `respond_to do |format| format.js end` in category's controller function. Instead I'm getting back empty HTML and "Processing by PhotosController#category as HTML" from the console.

Comment: This is injected into the head, the call which is routed to my `category` view thats supposed to return JS, but instead returns a 406: Not Acceptable. `<script type="text/javascript"> $(function($){ $.ajax({ type: "get", url: "/photos_js/category/urban" })}); </script>`. This is the same error I was getting calling the route directly, so it isn't a problem with the AJAX.

Comment: So trying to accomplish this with vanilla Rails (wiring up views just to serve JS) is a huge pain... managed to accomplish what I needed to do using gon. Marking this as accepted.