# update variable for js.erb file in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a partial with a form_for and a button. I render this partial with a activate_item.js.erb file and would like to have access to the instance variable in the index view.

activate_item.js.erb:

```
<%= form_for :c, url: activate_item_item_url(c.id), :html => {:id => "cc_form_#{c.id}", :class => "cc_form_class"}, :method => "put", :remote => true do |k| %>
<%= button_to "#{c.recyclable}", {:url => "activate_item_item_url", :controller => :items, :action => :activate_item, :id => "item_recyclable_#{c.id}"}, :class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm' %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @items.each do |c| %>
        <tr>   
          <td><%= c.description %></td>
          <td><%= c.color %></td>
             <% if c.active_recyclable_second %>
                <td><%= button_to "ON", {:controller => :items, :action => :activate_recyclable_second, :id => c.id}, :method => :put, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm' %></td>
             <% else %>
                <td><%= button_to "OFF", {:controller => :items, :action => :activate_recyclable_second, :id => c.id}, :method => :put, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm' %></td>
             <% end %>
             <div id="cc_form_ext_#{c.id}">
               <td><%= render "items/recyclable_update", c: c %></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

activate_item.js.erb:

```
$('#cc_form_ext_<%= @item.id %>').append('<%= escape_javascript(render 'recyclable_update') %>');
```

I've read that I need to update the c variable with a new ajax call. [Rails 3: Instance variable inaccessible in .js.erb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201523/rails-3-instance-variable-inaccessible-in-js-erb-file) but I'm not sure how to do that. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `c' for #<#<Class:0...............>):  <%= form_for :c, url: activate_item_item_url(c.id), :html => {:id => "cc_form_#{c.id}", :class %> etc.

Comment: I found it. I missed syntactically in the js.erb.
$('#cc_form_ext_<%= @item.id %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'recyclable_update', c: @item) %>');

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I missed syntactically to add c: @item in the js.erb. $('#cc_form_ext_<%= @item.id %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'recyclable_update', c: @item) %>');