# Ruby on Rails - Include javascript files from view folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My problem is the following:

I want to use <%render => "xx"%> in a js.erb file - so I can't put it in my assets folder because render doesn't work in asset files.

I already tried to name it index.js.erb to get rails to include it automatically(it lies in the view folder, see below) but I guess that doesn't get included because I deleted the require_tree line in my admin.js(It's the "application.js" for my admin namespace). I can't use require tree simple because I don't want every js file in assets/javascripts/admin to be included.

I got my js file here:

```
views/admin/benefits/index.js.erb
```

I want to use it in the following view:

```
views/admin/benefits/index.html.erb
```

Am i overcomplicating something here? If not, how would I include it in my view?
If it matters: I use rails 4.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I've got the same problem. I'm trying to use `render` and moved the .js.erb file to my Views folder.. but it now seems like the file isn't included in the asset pipeline at all.

Answer (score 1):

Move it to assets and add a optional `yield` to the `head` of your layout file.

In your layout file

```
<% if content_for?(:javascripts) %>
  yield(:javascripts)
<% end %>
```

In your view

```
<% content_for :javascripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'benefits/index' %>
<% end %>
```

I think you are misunderstanding what the use of this file. `js.erb` files allow you to use Ruby in your JavaScript file.  You can't actually render this file.  You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127697/js-erb-vs-js) to get a better understanding for why it is used.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain what `js.erb` files are used for.

Comment: I don't want to render the js file. I want to render a partial in a js call, simple as that. I could put the whole js code directly in my view and it would work but since that not good style I want it in an external js file.

Comment: Just have the js function return HTML from the js and insert it into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`js.erb` files are used with `respond_to` block, allowing the controller to respond to your Ajax request.

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
    format.js
    ...
  end
end
```

You then have a corresponding `app/views/users/create.js.erb` view file that generates the actual JavaScript code that will be sent and executed on the client side.

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");
```

More info [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)

In your case, you can define the javascript code in `assets/javascript/admin/benefits.js`, for example. Include only this file in `application.js` like:

```
//= require admin/benefits
```