# How to insert Ruby into JavaScript file OR use AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

So I have users that are filling out the latitude and longitude of a location. They are being stored under Location under lat and lng respectively. Right now I have it hard coded with the following in my JS file:

```
const markersByRegion = {
iowa: [{
        position: [39.988705, -86.061112],
        title: "Cedar Rapids"
    }]};
app.regions = () => {
  function init() {
      startGoogleMap();
  }

  let startGoogleMap = () => {
      let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("region-banner"), {
          zoom: 3,
          minZoom: 3,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          gestureHandling: "cooperative",
          styles: mapStyle
      });
      var mapElement = document.getElementById("region-banner");
      const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name')

      let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      markersByRegion[regionName].forEach(({ position, ...opts }) => {
          const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              ...opts,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(...position),
              map
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
```

In my Region > Show file I have the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="banner" id="region-banner" data-region-name="<%=@region.name.downcase%>">
<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.regions);</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is make this dynamic based on user input and assign markers based on the input.

EDIT:
So I tried, and failed, replacing the variable with something like:

```
const markersByRegion = {
 <%=Region.name%>: [{
   position: [<%=Location.lat%>, <%=Location.lng%>],
   title: '<%=Location.name%>' 
 }]
```

This results in the error in the console of Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:4). I've also tried putting data attributes in my region show page to pull the data but I'm running into the wall.

I then decided to make the change in my locations controller:

```
def marker
 @locations = Location.all
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @locations }
   format.html
 end
end
```

Then updated my region JS file to be:

```
import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';

app.regions = () => {
  function init() {
   startGoogleMap();
 }

 let startGoogleMap = () => {
   let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('region-banner'), {
    zoom: 3,
    minZoom: 3,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
    styles: mapStyle
  });
  var mapElement = document.getElementById('region-banner');
  const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name');

let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var promise = $.getJSON('/locations.json');

promise.done(function(data) {
  return $.each(data, function() {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng },
      map: map
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

So with this I'm now getting in console: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Which I thought I could address by just putting parseFloat in front of lat and lng but that just caused a different error of: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,.

Ultimately what I'm looking to do is that when a user logs a location with the latitude and longitude that they are entering under the Location model it dynamically updates on the region page.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your file to `your-script-name.js.erb`.
The order in which rails compiles the file is inverse to the file extensions order. In this case, for example, it will compile the .erb first (ruby code) and then the code will be interpreted as javascript.
You can check more about it here: [.js.erb VS .js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127697/js-erb-vs-js)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Webpacker really really did not like this attempt.

Comment: It was an issue with webpacker.jml and extensions issue. I updated the extensions to allow .js.erb and even .js.rjs files but the same issue persists. Nothing displays and the error code is the same in the console.

Answer (score 0):

ERB interpolation in JS is generally a bad idea since it makes your scripts un-cacheable, un-minified  and hard to test.

If you simply want to draw a single point on a map you can attach it to the document by using data attributes:

```
<div class="thing" data-lat="<%= @location.lat%>" data-lng="<%= @location.lng%>">
```

If you want to draw a bunch of markers or do it dynamically then using ajax to fetch json data is the way to do it:

```
class ThingsController
  def index
     @things = Thing.all
     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @things }
     end
  end
end
```

---

```
var promise = $.getJSON('/things.json');

promise.done(function(data){
  return $.each(data, function(){
    return new google.maps.Marker({
       position: { lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng },
       map: map
       // ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There are also plenty of more hacky ways like `<script>window.someglobal = <%= some_data.to_json %></script>`.

Comment: Actually looking to do dynamic based on user input. It's the right ajax call to replace what's there that I'm struggling with.

Comment: Can't really help you there without knowing what it you're actually building.